# Change existing subscriptions fees (Paypal)

Tags: paypal

How do I change recurring subscriptions fees, I want to increase prices of already existing subscriptions, Prices have increased but automatic payments are using old prices instead of new ones

Comment: Hi Melvin, don't want to assume anything here but how did you take these Sub Payments; from a subscription button? From Express Checkout using APIs?

Comment: Checkout not a button

Comment: Ok. Here is the Update Recurring Profile to alter the amts.https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/merchant/UpdateRecurringPaymentsProfile_API_Operation_NVP/